# Find the multiplicity of eigenvalue $2a$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, kronecker-product

Let $a,b$ be real numbers with $0<2a<b$. Let $K_n$ denote the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) of order $n$, and let  $A$ be the $n^2\times n^2$  matrix defined by

$$A:=a[vec(I_n)vec(I_n)'+K_n-2diag(K_n)+I_{n^2}]+bdiag(K_n)$$

where $vec$ denotes the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) , and $diag(C)$ denotes the diagonal matrix having the same diagonal as $C$. Finally let $M$ be an $n\times n$ idempotent matrix with rank $r<n$, and let $B$ be the matrix defined by

$$B:=[M\otimes M]A[M \otimes M]$$

where $\otimes$ denotes the [kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). I am trying to find the multiplicity of eigenvalue $2a$ as a function of  $M$. Also I would like to show that $2a$ is the smallest nonzero eigenvalue of $B$.

After some work I found that the eigenvalues of $A$ are as follows :

- $b+na  \, \text{   with multiplicity } 1 \, \text{and eigenvector} \sum_{i=1}^n (e_i\otimes e_i),$
- $b  \text{   with multiplicty } n-1 \, \text{and eigenvectors} \, \{(e_1\otimes e_1)-(e_i\otimes e_i), i=2,\dots, n\},$
- $2a  \, \text{   with multiplicty } n(n-1)/2 \, \text{and eigenvectors} \, \{(e_i\otimes e_j)+(e_j\otimes e_i), i\neq j\},$
- $0  \, \text{   with multiplicty } n(n-1)/2 \, \text{and eigenvectors} \, \{(e_i\otimes e_j)-(e_j\otimes e_i), i \neq j\},$

where $e_i$ denotes the $n\times 1$ vector with $1$ in position $i$ and zeros elsewhere.  I believe the multiplicity of $2a$ corresponds to the dimension of the $Col(M\otimes M) \cap Col(R)$, where $R$ denotes the $n^2\times n(n-1)/2$ matrix having columns $(e_i\otimes e_j)+(e_j\otimes e_i)$ for $i\neq j$, and $Col$ denotes the column space.

Any ideas how to proceed? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user1551 Right I made an edit. Am trying to compute the multiplicity of eigenvalue $2a$ as a function of $rank(M)$ and $n$.

Comment: @user1551 Ok I will add details tomorrow to clarify.

Comment: @user1551 I took a step back. I would like to show that the multiplicity of $2a$ corresponds to the dimension of $Col(M\otimes M) \cap Col(R)$ and that the eigenvalues smaller than $2a$ are all zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By replacing $A$ by $\frac{1}{a}A$, we may assume that $a=1$ and $b>2$. With respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the matrix $A$ represents the linear operator $f:\mathbb R^{n\times n}\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ defined by
$$
f(X)=\operatorname{tr}(X)I_n+(X+X^T)+(b-2)\operatorname{diag}(X).
$$
Hence $B$ represents the linear operator $g$ defined by
\begin{align}
g(X)&=Mf(MXM)M\\
&=M\left[\operatorname{tr}(MXM)I+MXM+(MXM)^T+(b-2)\operatorname{diag}(MXM)\right]M.\tag{0}
\end{align}
Observe that $g(X)=0$ when $X$ is skew-symmetric or when $MXM=0$. Hence
$$
K=\{X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}:X=-X^T\}+\{X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}:MXM=0\}\subseteq\ker g.
$$
As $g$ is self-adjoint (because $B$ is symmetric), in order to determine other eigenvectors or eigenvalues of $g$, it suffices to consider the restriction of $g$ on
$$
K^\perp=\{X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}:X=MYM \text{ for some symmetric matrix } Y\}.
$$
Suppose $X\in K^\perp$. Then $MXM=M^2YM^2=MYM=X=X^T$. If this $X$ is an eigenvector $g$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$
\lambda X=g(X)
=\operatorname{tr}(X)M+2X+(b-2)M\operatorname{diag}(X)M.\tag{1}
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\lambda\|X\|_F^2
&=\langle X,\lambda X\rangle\\
&=\langle X,\,\operatorname{tr}(X)M+2X+(b-2)M\operatorname{diag}(X)M\rangle\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X)\langle X,M\rangle+2\|X\|_F^2+(b-2)\langle X,M\operatorname{diag}(X)M\rangle\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X)\operatorname{tr}(XM)+2\|X\|_F^2+(b-2)\operatorname{tr}(XM\operatorname{diag}(X)M)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X)\operatorname{tr}(XM^2)+2\|X\|_F^2+(b-2)\operatorname{tr}(XM\operatorname{diag}(X)M)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X)\operatorname{tr}(MXM)+2\|X\|_F^2+(b-2)\operatorname{tr}(MXM\operatorname{diag}(X))\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X)\operatorname{tr}(X)+2\|X\|_F^2+(b-2)\operatorname{tr}(X\operatorname{diag}(X))\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X)^2+2\|X\|_F^2+(b-2)\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ii}^2\\
&\ge2\|X\|_F^2.\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
Hence $g$ is positive definite on $K^\perp$, $\ker g=K$, every positive eigenvalue of $g$ is $\ge2$, and
$$
\operatorname{rank}(B)=\operatorname{rank}(g)=\dim K^\perp=\frac{1}{2}m(m+1),
$$
where $m$ denotes the rank of $M$. Moreover, $2$ is an eigenvalue of $g$ only if equality holds in $(2)$, i.e., only if $X$ is hollow ($\operatorname{diag}(X)=0$). This condition is also sufficient: if
$$
X\in S=\left\{X\in K^\perp:\operatorname{diag}(X)=0\right\}\tag{3}
$$
or equivalently, if $\operatorname{vec}(X)\in S_1=\operatorname{col}(M\otimes M)\cap\operatorname{col}(R)$ where $R$ is defined as in your question, then by $(0)$ we get $g(X)=2X$. Thus the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $2$ is equal to $\dim S\,(=\dim S_1)$.

This dimension can be zero. That is, $2$ is not necessarily an eigenvalue of $B$ or $g$. One obvious example is given by $M=0$, which makes $S=0$. For a non-trivial example, just try a numerical experiment that repeatedly samples some random orthogonal projectors $M\in\mathbb R^{3\times3}$ of rank $2$. Sometimes $2$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, but most of the time it isn't.

Since our problem formulation involves $\operatorname{diag}(X)$ or $\operatorname{diag}(MXM)$, it is not basis independent and we expect a nice answer when $M$ is, up to a permutation of rows and columns, in the form of $I_m\oplus0$ (where $m$ denotes the rank of $M$). Indeed, in this case one can easily see that the matrix subspace in $(3)$ consists of matrices of the form $F\oplus0$, where $F$ is any $m\times m$ hollow symmetric matrix. Therefore $2$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $\frac12m(m-1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer! Do you think its possible to pin down the exact multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue? (as a function of $M$).

Comment: @Alphie I don't see any explicit answer ($\dim S$ is already a function of $M$, but it really isn't an explicit answer). When the rank of $M$ is $0,1$ or $n$, we do know explicitly the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $2$: it is $0$ when the rank is $\le1$ and $\frac12n(n-1)$ when the rank is $n$. Things get much more complicated, however, when $2\le\operatorname{rank}(M)<n$. ...

Comment: ...E.g. when the rank is $2$, we can express $M$ as $uu^T+vv^T$ for two orthonormal vectors $u$ and $v$. In this case, if I am not mistaken, it can be shown that $\dim S$ is equal to the nullity of the matrix $\pmatrix{u&v&u\circ v}$ where $u\circ v$ denotes the Hadamard (i.e., entrywise) product of $u$ and $v$. That is, it depends on whether $u\circ v$ lies inside the linear span of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Ok I was hoping we could express the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue as the dimension of some subspace. Can we say something about the rank of $B$?

Comment: In the case where $2$ is an eigenvalue my simulations seem to indicate that the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is $n(n-1)- \text{dim} \,S$. Basically we add $n(n-1)/2- \text{dim} \,S$ to $n(n-1)/2$. Do you see why?

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why $\dim K^\perp=\frac{1}{2}m(m+1)$? So in fact the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is $n^2-\dim K^\perp$ right?

Comment: @Alphie By a change of orthonormal basis we may assume that $M=I_m\oplus0$. In this case $K^\perp$ consists of all symmetric matrices of the form $S\oplus0$ where $S$ is any $m\times m$ symmetric matrix. Hence $\dim K^\perp=\frac12m(m+1)$.

Comment: Alternatively, write $M=UU^T$ where $U\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ has $m$ orthonormal columns $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_m$. Then every matrix in the form of $MYM$ with a symmetric $Y$ can be expressed as a linear combination of matrices of the forms $u_iu_i^T$ and $u_iu_j^T+u_ju_i^T$ with $i<j$. Since these matrices are linearly independent and there are $\frac12m(m+1)$ of them, the result follows.

Comment: @Alphie Your claim that “when $2$ is an eigenvalue the nullity of $B$ is $n(n-1)=\dim S$” is false. E.g. when $n=3,\,b=3$ and $M=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$, the nine eigenvalues of $B$ are $2,3,5$ and six copies of zero. Therefore $n(n-1)-\dim S=3\times2-1=5\ne6=\operatorname{nullity}(B)$.